# Get the full contents of any section of an ELF file in C code

Tags: c, elf, objdump

I want to get the full contents of any sections in an ELF file,

I can get the name of the content with this code:

```
int fd;
int counter;
int filesize;
void *data;
char *strtab;
Elf64_Ehdr  *elf;
Elf64_Shdr  *shdr;

counter = 0;
fd = open(av[1], O_RDONLY);
if (fd == -1) {
    perror("open : ");
    return (84);
}
filesize = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
data = mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
if (data != NULL) {
    elf = (Elf64_Ehdr *)(data);
    shdr = (Elf64_Shdr *)(data + elf->e_shoff);
    strtab = (char *)(data + shdr[elf->e_shstrndx].sh_offset);
    while(counter < elf->e_shnum) {
        printf("Contents of section %s:\n", &strtab[shdr[counter].sh_name]);
        counter ++;
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
perror("mmap : ");
return (EXIT_FAILURE);
```

I found that the `shdr` structure contain many pieces of information but I want the information given by the `objdump -s a.out` command and I can’t find the structure that gives all the information.

Can you help me to find a lead or a name of a structure where I can find this information, please?

Comment: `void` pointer arithmetic is undefined behavior. You can fix that with `(Elf64_Shdr *)((char *)data + elf->e_shoff)`

Comment: Do you want the disassembly, or just code in binary form?

Comment: i want to get information in this format:

`Contents of section .rodata:
 0000 67452301 efcdab89 67452301 efcdab89  gE#.....gE#.....
 0010 64636261 68676665 64636261 68676665  dcbahgfedcbahgfe`

Comment: look at the code of `objdump`? The question as it stands is way to broad.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug:

```
if (data != NULL) {
```

because `mmap` doesn't return `NULL` on failure (it returns `MAP_FAILED`).

Your `shdr` variable points to `struct Elf64_Shdr`, which has `.sh_offset` and `.sh_size` fields. To get the *contents* of the section, you want to dump `.sh_size` bytes located at `(char *)data + shdr->sh_offset`.